# HTML2PDF not possible load chart.googleapis.com qr code?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dom-events, html2pdf

When I use `html2pdf()` function to download in PDF format, in that image is not displaying rendering from link. Below mentioned link used, it leaves blank space in PDF. Not displaying any image in PDF.

```
"https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=http://hellovcard.com/6160175f9b7f3&choe=UTF-8&chof=gif"

<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=http://hellovcard.com/6160175f9b7f3&choe=UTF-8&chof=gif" alt="qr code">
```

Code I have used:

```
 function saveAsPDF() {
            var element = document.getElementById('printableArea');
            var opt = {
                margin: 0.3,
                filename: 'download.pdf',
                image: {type: 'jpeg', quality: 1},
                html2canvas: {scale: 4, dpi: 72, letterRendering: true},
                jsPDF: {unit: 'in', format: 'A2'},
                html2canvas: {
                    onclone: (element) => {
                        const svgElements = Array.from(element.querySelectorAll('svg'));
                        svgElements.forEach(s => {
                            const bBox = s.getBBox();
                            s.setAttribute("x", bBox.x);
                            s.setAttribute("y", bBox.y);
                            s.setAttribute("width", bBox.width);
                            s.setAttribute("height", bBox.height);
                      })
                }
                },
            };
            html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();

        }
```

[image]

Comment: this is possibly due to "tainted canvas" (e.g.: canvas which content have CORS element). You can try to proxy the content of the canvas with server-side scripting (e.g.: php/node) so the canvas is not considered as CORS.

Comment: This work for me: `{ allowTaint: false, useCORS: true }`

Comment: @JheymanMejia no not working

Comment: I used this API for QR https://goqr.me/api/doc/create-qr-code/